# Caffe MemoryData Layer and Solver inteface

Tags: python, caffe

I am trying to train a network but rather using lmdb or leveldb, I am feeding data to my network on the fly. So I am following procedure as outlined below

1. My data is loaded in Memory Data Layer.
2. I create a mini batch using a python script.
3. Set data and label as `solver.net.set_input_arrays(batch,labels)`
4. After that I call `solver.step(1)`

Here solver is of type SGDSolver. Now my question is what is the difference between `solver.solve()` and `solver.step()`?

2ndly this approach doesn't let me have a memory data layer for test network. Is there any work around for that?

My solver.prototxt looks like

```
net: "/path/to/train_val.prototxt"
base_lr: 0.01
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100000
display: 20
max_iter: 450000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "/path/to/temporal_net_train"
solver_mode: GPU
```

With my approach every 20th iteration network displays some output loss etc. And somehow loss stays constant over some numbert of iterations, what could be the reason for that.

Comment: you asked several questions in your post. you might want to consider posting them as different questions?

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the difference between solver.solve and solver.step?

**solve** does the entire training run, to whatever limits you've set -- usually the iteration limit.  **step** does only the specified number of iterations.

2. How do I get a memory data layer for test network?

If you're not reading from a supported data channel / format, I *think* you have to write a customer input routine (your **data** package).

3. Loss stays constant over multiple iterations, what could be the reason?

There are several possibilities, depending on the surrounding effects.  If the loss shows only one value ever, then your back propagation is a likely culprit.  Perhaps you're not properly connected to the data set, and you're not getting the expected classifications fed in.

If the loss has a temporary stability but then converges decently, don't worry about it; this is likely an effect of training ordering.

If the loss declines decently and then settles at a fixed value, then you're also doing well: the training converged before it ran out of iterations.