# Caffe LeNet: Difference between `solver.step(1)` and `solver.net.forward()`

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I was checking the Caffe LeNet Tutorial [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/01-learning-lenet.ipynb) and a question came to mind:

What's the difference between these 2 codes:

```
self.solver.step(1)
```

and

```
self.solver.net.forward()  # train net
```

They both seem to train the network at least according to the comment.

Personally I think the first one trains the network on the training data and updates the weights of both `net` and `test_net` but the second one seems to only forward a batch of data and apply the learned weights from the previous step.

If what I think is right, then what is the purpose of the second code in the tutorial? why did the code do a `net.forward` ? can't `solver.step(1)` do this itself?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**step** does one full iteration, covering all three phases: **forward** evaluation, **backward** propagation, and **update**.  The call to **forward** does only the first of these.  There are also differences in the signature (parameter list).

Comment: Thanks... if batch_size is 100 (out of 2000 Images), then does step() do the 3 phases on 100 batches or 2000 batches ?

Comment: Step does only one iteration: a single batch of 100 images.  Doing a full set of 20 batches (all 2000 inputs) is called an *epoch*.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Thanks for the up-vote and green check.

Comment: @Prune : what does solver.solve() do? suppose I have 200 iters, 2000 images and batch of 100. 
Do I do : 
for 1 until iter 
   solver.step(1)
   test, etc
or should I do 
for 1 until iter
      solver.step(20)
      test, etc 
? 
or should I only use solver.solve()?

Comment: See partial answer #1 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352820/caffe-memorydata-layer-and-solver-inteface/39089447#39089447).  The difference depends on whether you want to intervene after 20 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a strange behavior in `solver.step(1)` and `solver.net.forward()`. When I used a custom layer for the input network, my instance layer needs a variable before using:

```
solver.net.layers[0].mySet(variable)
```

That `variable` was set in a local variable for my layer. But when I called for solver.step, that variable does not appear. However it does, when I use `solver.net.forward()`.  I am not certain, but maybe `solver.step` is instantiating a new variable for the layer.

Comment: is this an answer? or us it a new question?

Comment: Actually, this is both. I was using a layer with:
``` self.solver.net.layers[0].set_data(data) ```, where in that layer got

```
def set_data(self, data):
        self._data = data
```
But, when I call ```solver.step(1)```, they returns 
```
AttributeError: 'DataLayer' object has no attribute '_data' 
```